# elasticsearch nested query, i think

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, mapping, subquery

I come from a related database background and something like this would be so simple there, but I can't figure this out.  I've been trying to learn Elasticsearch for a week or so and I'm trying to figure out what I think is a nested query.  Here's some sample data:

```
PUT /myindex/pets/_mapping
{
   "pets": {
      "properties": {
         "name": {
            "type": "string"
         },
         "pet": {
            "type": "nested", 
            "properties": {
               "name": {"type": "string"}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

POST /myindex/pets/
{"pet": {"name": "rosco"}, "name": "sam smith"}

POST /myindex/pets/
{"pet": {"name": "patches"}, "name": "sam smith"}

POST /myindex/pets
{"pet": {"name": "rosco"}, "name": "jack mitchell"}
```

What would the query look like that only returns documents matching:

- owner name is "sam smith"
- pet name is "rosco"

I've tried a mixmatch of `bool`, `match`, `nested`, `filtered/filter` type queries, but I just keep getting errors.  Stuff like this stands out in the errors:

```
nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT \"nested\"];
```

Here was the query:

```
GET /myindex/pets/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "sam smith"
    },
    "nested": {
      "path": "pet",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "pet.name": "rosco"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm beginning to think that I just can't target something this specific due to the *relevant* nature of Elasticsearch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Man, these queries are tricky sometimes...  This seems to work:

```
GET /myindex/pets/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "name": "sam smith"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "pet",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "pet.name": "rosco"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```